# python tqdm package miniters not working occasionally

Tags: python, tqdm

Since I'm looping over permutations I don't want too frequent updates of the progress bar, so I set miniters to be one-tenth of the total length:

```
total_len = len(list(itertools.permutations(range(N), 2)))
for row_a, row_b in tqdm(itertools.permutations(range(N), 2), total=total_len , miniters=int(total_len/10), disable=disable):
```

[image: Sometimes it works fine]

[image: but it can fail in other cases]

Any idea what's causing this unstable performance of miniters?

Answer (score 3):

I think I found the reason, another argument maxinterval controls the maximum update interval which is set to 10 (seconds) by default, so when the progress bar updates too slowly it'll automatically modify the miniters parameter. Therefore I'll need to specify a larger maxinterval as well.

So the code should be

```
total_len = len(list(itertools.permutations(range(N), 2)))
# or a larger value than 200 (seconds)
for row_a, row_b in tqdm(itertools.permutations(range(N), 2), total=total_len , miniters=int(total_len/10), maxinterval=200, disable=disable):
```